# Exchange old US dollar bills in Australia

Tags: money, australia, exchange, brisbane

I am in Brisbane and have two $100 US dollar bills from the 1985 series. I went to money exchanges and banks, but no one is accepting it. Any idea where I can change them in Australia and, in particular, the Queensland area?

Comment: You can use them in the US.  I realize this doesn't answer your question (hence this is comment rather than an answer), but it may be possible for you to exchange them with a traveler bound for the US.  They might even give you a better rate.